# How to show result of looping like console.log did in the react-native. here's my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the problem for this situation. I want to print like console.log did in the screen for react native[image]

`

```
const dString = text;
  const days = 30;

  let [day, month, year] = dString.split('/');

  // month - 1 as month in the Date constructor is zero indexed
  const now = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
  let loopDay = now;
  for (let i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
    loopDay.setDate(loopDay.getDate() + 6);
    console.log ('Day: ' + loopDay);
  }
```

here's my code and I want to print in return of function in react-native so result of looping can show on my screen`

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by adding all the loop days to an array like so:

To increase the date you can multiply by `i` to increase the offset.

```js
const loopDays = [];
const now = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
for (let i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
  const loopDay = new Date(now);
  loopDay.setDate(loopDay.getDate() + 6 * (i + 1));
  console.log("Day: " + loopDay);
  loopDays.push(loopDay);
}
```

And the you can display them by looping over the `loopDays` like so

```js
return (
  <View>
    {loopDays.map((day) => {
      return <Text>Day: {day}</Text>;
    })}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. but I have another problem.. the problem is only last date who display on the screen and looping as much as I declare in function.. what should I do if I want to print all of date like function did?

Comment: I don't really understand your question here, the current code will display all the `loopDays` that are in the array.

Comment: my output is like this:
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
02/05/2023
only last statement of loopDays array who display in the screen.. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const ShowDates = () => {
    const dString = '29/10/2022';
    const days = 30;

    let [day, month, year] = dString.split('/');

    // month - 1 as month in the Date constructor is zero indexed
    const now = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    let loopDay = now;

    let tempArray = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
      loopDay.setDate(loopDay.getDate() + 6);
      tempArray.push(loopDay);
    } 

    return tempArray;
  } 

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',paddingTop:30}}>
    {ShowDates()?.map((item,index)=>(
      <Text key={index}>Day : {item.toLocaleString()} </Text>
    ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiBv8.png)

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot for give me a solved.. but I have another problem, my output is only last statement of showDates array that display on screen and looping as much as I set in the function like in the "Solution Image" That you send.. If I want to display all of date in the showDates array, what should I do?

Comment: we are already looping through all the showDates array elements ... what other you want to display ? can you provide some example of what you want  to display .